# Android app failing to connect local host

Tags: android, localhost, retrofit

Trying to connect to local Api on local server 5000 and Fail

Connecting by browser to http:/127.0.0.1:5000/user/1
works fine.

connecting to external api also work fine.

trying to connect to same address with android retrofit ,
keep getting
Skipped xxx frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android_movieapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidmovieApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MovieListActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Problem solved by

1. url = 10.0.2.2
2. add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
   to manifest  application tag.

Comment: can I see your code? can you also post your manifest application tag.

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: yes , using emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Emulator is an emulated separate device. Localhost addresses like 127.0.0.1 will therefore resolve to the localhost of the Android emulator NOT your computer that you are running it on.

You should instead use the address

> 10.0.2.2

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: checked it already , and not working. 
not sure t it related , i try to connect to local server to retrieve data , and only later use data on app.

Comment: So is it failing to connect or failing to get data... those are very different things.

Comment: i am aware.  yet problem remains , connection to local api fail.

Comment: Problem solved with 10.0.2.2 As suggested
and adding
        ```android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"```
to manifest application tag.